# Does continue prevent the else block from running in a for/else statement?

Tags: python

In a `for` loop with `break` statements I can add an `else` statement at the end, which will be triggered if my `for` loop never hits a `break` statement.

My question is, how does `continue` affect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`continue` does not affect the `else:` clause. The `else` clause is run if the loop terminated normally, that is, [if a `StopIteration` is (implicitly) raised by the iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement).

The `continue` statement does nothing for the particular iteration, however it does not prevent the iterator from being exhausted.

Answer (score 2):

No, `else` clause execution is not affected by `continue`.

The only thing that prevents an `else` statement (after a for loop) from being triggered is a `break` statement (or your code `return`ing or exiting or raising an exception before it finishes the `for` loop).

```
for i in range(5):
    continue
else:
    print("else triggered")
```

Will print `else triggered`.

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops):

> Loop statements may have an `else` clause; it is executed when the loop terminates through exhaustion of the list (with `for`) or when the condition becomes false (with `while`), but not when the loop is terminated by a `break` statement
>
> [...]
>
> When used with a loop, the `else` clause has more in common with the `else` clause of a `try` statement than it does that of `if` statements: a `try` statement’s `else` clause runs when no exception occurs, and a loop’s `else` clause runs when no `break` occurs.

Only `break` is mentioned as preventing the `else` clause from running, `continue` isn't.